# How to change the background color of qtooltip of a qtablewidget item?

Tags: qt, qtablewidgetitem

I have a qtablewidget. There are certain cells (qtablewidgetitem) in this table that need to show error message via qtooltip. I wish to change the background color of tooltip of each cell so as to highlight the tooltip message better. How can it be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best way is the use of style sheets. You can set any text colors/background colors and text style that way.

Depending on your QT version, see the documentation:

[Qt5 Style Sheet Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Though an exhaustive one, the above documentation was of good help. I added following code to add customized tooltip to my qtablewidget => ui.ansTable->setStyleSheet("QToolTip{border: 2px solid orange; padding: 5px; border-radius: 3px; opacity: 200;}"); where ui.ansTable is a qtablewidget.

Answer (score 3):

you can use QtoolTip static methodes to update the palette :

```
QPalette palette = QToolTip::palette();
palette.setColor(QPalette::ToolTipBase,QColor("#F6F6F6")); // light grey
palette.setColor(QPalette::ToolTipText,QColor("#706F6F"));//dark grey for text
QToolTip::setPalette(palette);
```